# ASP.NET error "The process cannot access the file"

Tags: c#, filestream, file-copying

Having worked through some of the fixes on SO, I'm still no further forward in solving this issue.

I have the following code to read a file, then close it, then move it to another (archive) folder.

The read and process works fine, but the move/copy error on "The process cannot access the file...because it is being used by another process."

```
FileStream aStream = new FileStream(aFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamReader checkf = new StreamReader(aStream);
ArrayList lineList = new ArrayList();
string aLine;
while ((aLine = checkf.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lineList.Add(aLine);
}
checkf.Close();
checkf.Dispose();
aStream.Close();
aStream.Dispose();

if (lineList[lineList.Count - 1].ToString().Contains("LastLine"))
{
     // Process File....
}
else
{
    output.WriteLine("ERROR: No LastLine" + aFile);
}

System.IO.File.Copy(aFile, aFile.Replace("acuploads", "acuploads/ac_upload_archive"), true);
```

Comment: I think that file opened in your desktop

Comment: You're over using `Close()` and `Dispose()`. Consider using the `using () {}` statement instead.

Comment: I'm curious, do you have `aFile` open anywhere else? Considering you use `FileShare.ReadWrite` the copy *should* work.

Comment: See which process is accessing the File . It will give you a Head-start . http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm

Comment: @Lloyd This is the entirety of the process.  File's not references anywhere else in the code.

Comment: @spetzz even after a reboot and running this before anything else, I get the error.

Comment: I thought it might be dropbox (as my dev projects are hosted in a dropbox folder) but even moving the project to a desktop folder, same issue.

Comment: Same issue occurs if I copy it up to the production server.  So it must be a programmatic problem.

Comment: Replace the "line reading part" with "File.ReadAllLines()" and check if the problem is solved